# Calling Java app with "subprocess" from Python and reading the Java app output

Tags: java, python, communication

What is the nicest way to read the output (i.e. via System.out.println) of a Java app which is called from Python with

```
subprocess.Popen("java MyClass", shell=True)
```

without writing and reading a file? (Using Jython etc is not a possible solution)

Comment: sidenote: prefer the syntax given by S. Mark below when using subprocess.Popen (i.e. the list for the first argument, and the default value for shell (False). See http://www.logilab.org/blogentry/20469 for more on this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
p1 = subprocess.Popen(["/usr/bin/java", "MyClass"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
print p1.stdout.read()
```

Comment: Use Popen.communicate() to perform a blocking read until popened process terminates.

Answer (score 3):

I just found the solution:

```
p = subprocess.Popen("java MyClass",
          shell=True,
          stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output, errors = p.communicate()
```

S.Mark's is fine too!

Comment: I was unable to call `javac src/*.java` by passing a list to Popen due to the wildcard, not sure why. Giving a string and using `communicate()` works