# Unable to read file when Java application is invoked from python

Tags: java, python, python-3.x

I have a Java program, reading a file (which has characters from a native language), and populating a string. It works fine, when program is run directly.

But when same program is invoked from Python then its not able to populate the string.

```
        public static void main(String[] args) {
        File inputFile = new File("input.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(inputFile),"UTF-8"));
      string output = "";
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
           // This block never hits when invoked by python. It works fine when java program runs directly.
           output +=line+" ";
         }
         ...
         }
```

From Python I am invoking it as following

```
cmd = ['java', java_class]
subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Any inputs? btw I am using Atom IDE, not sure if that makes any difference.

Comment: What is the error that you are getting?

Comment: no error. Its just that my output comes empty instead of having contents of file

Comment: Check this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2388423/calling-java-app-with-subprocess-from-python-and-reading-the-java-app-output

Comment: @TheRoy, thanks for sharing the link. But not sure if this link helps, it just tells that how to read the java program's output in python. I am able to invoke the java application from python. Issue is that when java application is invoked from python then its not able to read the content of a file, which is perfectly readable when java application is run directly.

Answer (score 1):

I tried your example and it worked for me. Let's see if it works for you. I will then respond to you what I think about the issue.

```
import java.io.*;


public class Python2JavaMessaging {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
                try {
                        BufferedReader bufferRead = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
                        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("result.txt", "UTF-8");
                        String s = bufferRead.readLine();
                        while(s.equals("x")==false) {
                                writer.println(s);
                                s = bufferRead.readLine();
                        }
                        writer.close();
                } catch(IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
}
```

The Python script is as below:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import subprocess

cmd = ['java', '-classpath', '.' , 'Python2JavaMessaging']
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, encoding='utf8')

p.stdin.write("First line\r\n")
p.stdin.write("Second line\r\n")
p.stdin.write("x\r\n") # this line will not be printed into the file
```

Comment: btw, I have used stdin to write. We can change it to a file as well. In your case, input.txt

Comment: Can you please help me by providing the sample with a file. Also, just to highlight again if my file content is english then everything works fine. It does not work only when i have file content in some native language.

Comment: you will need to use the right encoding for that. I have used encoding in my example. Try your native language specific encoding.

Comment: Check this post for writing to a file. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15535240/python-popen-write-to-stdout-and-log-file-simultaneously

Comment: If you think your query is resolved with these, then please accept the answer to close the thread.

Comment: I have tried the exact code that you have shared, but result.txt is empty for me

Comment: Can you make sure that the java file as well as the python files are running in the same directory?

Comment: yes they are placed in the same directory, thats why result.txt has been created, right?

Comment: The only other thing you may want to check is - 1. You run the java program first 2. You make sure your python version is 3+

Comment: What does you mean run the java program first. It is the python script which is going to run the java program. Right?